# Wrong distance estimation in MATLAB from stereo images generated in Blender

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera, blender, stereo-3d

I am trying to simulate a stereo camera in Blender and to measure the distance, but I am having some issues with measuring the distance of the cameras from the checkerboard pattern.

In Blender, I set the cameras resolution to 640 x 480 px, the baseline to 20 cm, and I am using the parameters preset shown below. The maximum distance between the cameras and the pattern, in Blender, is ~20 m.

[image]

I have taken several synthetic pairs of pictures, and I have been able to import in the MATLAB stereo camera calibrator eight pairs. The result of the calibration is shown below.
[image]

According to the obtained results, the distance measured by the cameras when the object is ~20 m away (Blender ground truth) is ~900 m, and I can't understand why. Moreover, the translation vector of the second camera relative to the first camera is t = [-20.0160512658773,   -0.118042169030331, -328.082851181787], therefore the baseline is correctly measured, but there is something off with the z.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably entered a wrong square size for the points of the checkerboard.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I measured the exact distance in Blender and that matches what I entered in Matlab. I also tried to express the same distance with different units (in the calibrator it is possible to choose between millimeters, centimeters, and inches) but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't know - if it was me, I'd try to gain some insight by removing some variables. For example, try to solve for the matchmove inside blender first, assuming the exact camera parameters. Also, add some perspective foreshortening by rotating the target.